# Como obtener un archivo (pdf,Imagen) desde laravel 9 y mostrar ese archivo en Front en Angular?

Tags: laravel

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahi trato de obtener la ruta de mi archivo.... para recibirlo en angular y despues mostrarlo en un iframe

Comment: Agrega el código para ver que problema tienes.

Comment: Hola  Ryuk  bienvenido, la pregunta debe ser autocontenida, esto es que no dependa de imágenes o enlaces, por favor, edita tu pregunta, elimina las imágenes, y agrega tu código y mensajes de error como texto, así evitarás recibir votos negativos y lograrás que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida, gracias, podrías indicarnos que problema tienes?.